# Kendo ui: Cannot bind text value and button click event to viewModel for dynamically created HTML content

Tags: jquery, data-binding, kendo-ui, dynamic-binding, kendo-mvvm

I am using `Kendo MVVM` and binding text field value and button click event to the `viewModel` using `data attribute`.

I can successfully bind the default value for the textbox and click event of the button that are initially rendered on the page.

But when I dynamically generate textbox and button, I am not able to bind the value and the click event to the `viewModel`.

Here is my working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/xvx4y6Lx/). Below is my code:

**JS:**

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    textValue: 1,
    buttonClick: function(e) {
        alert("button click");
    },
  generateDynamicContent: function() {
    var html = '<input data-bind="value: dynamicTextValue" name="dynamicTextValue"/><input type="button" value="Dynamic Button" data-bind="click: dynamicButtonClick"/>';

        $('#dynamicContent').append(html);

  },
    dynamicTextValue: 2,
    dynamicButtonClick: function(e) {
        alert("dynamic button click");
    },
});
kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="example">
<input data-bind="value: textValue" name="textValue"/>
<input type="button" value="Button" data-bind="click: buttonClick"/>

<br />
<input type="button" value="Generate Dynamic Content" data-bind="click: generateDynamicContent"/>

<br/>
<div id="dynamicContent">
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code**

add `kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);` after appending html

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    textValue: 1,
    buttonClick: function(e) {
        alert("button click");
    },
  generateDynamicContent: function(e) {
    var html = '<input data-bind="value: dynamicTextValue" name="dynamicTextValue"/><input type="button" value="Dynamic Buttondddd" data-bind="click: dynamicButtonClick"/>';

    $('#example').append(html);
    //--------THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT
    kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
  },
    dynamicTextValue: 2,
    dynamicButtonClick: function(e) {
        alert("dynamic button click");
    },
});

kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e1cbz7Ls/)

Comment: Glad to help you:)